# Which sentence is correct, "I like reading books." or "I like books reading."?

Tags: phrase-choice

I read somewhere:

- Race(adjective) Horse(noun)
- Horse(adjective) Race(noun)
- They caught the guy wearing(present participle) the red jacket the other day.
- I like books reading(present participle) in the library.

then by considering these references above both sentences should be true. Are they?

Comment: I can't follow your logic here- can you [edit] to add some details and clarify what your thought-process here is?

Answer (score 1):

"Race" and "Horse" are both nouns, which can be combined to form a compound nouns in different ways. A "racehorse" is a type of horse that is used for racing and a "horse race" is race between horses.

Don't make the mistake of thinking that every time you see a word in front of a noun, then that word must be an adjective.  Race(noun)-horse(noun).

The example with the "guy wearing a red jacket" is good.  The word "wearing" is a verb in it's participle form. It heads the clause "wearing a red jacket" that describes the guy.

But "I like books reading in the library" is incorrect, or at least unnatural.  Here "reading in the library" is a particle clause that describes what the books are doing.  But that doesn't make sense, since books can't read (only people are able to read).  So this is wrong.

The correct construction should be

> I like reading books in the library.

Here "reading books in the library" is the participle clause, with "books" the object of the verb "reading".

Comment: 1. I like reading(gerund) books(object of gerund).                                                              
2. I like books(noun adjunct) reading(gerund).                          Are these sentences broken right?

Comment: You can have "I like book reading"  with the noun adjunct in the singular.  But this isn't a particular natural expression and should be avoided.

Comment: The construction of compound like "horse race" is strongly defined by idiom.  The compound "book reading" just isn't very idiomatic.

Comment: THANK YOU SIR JAMES

Comment: I haven't received a knighthood yet, and so just "James" please

Comment: @JamesK - my wife calls me 'Lord Henry', and I am neither a peer nor called Henry.

Answer (score 0):

"Reading" here is a verb, not an adjective. So the correct word order is "I like reading books". (Or more likely, "I like to read books.") That is, subject - verb - object. (The sentence is a bit more complicated because of the "like", but the principle is the same.)

If you were talking about "reading" as a noun, the activity of reading, it would be grammatically correct to say, "I like book reading". That is, I like reading, and the specific type of reading that I like is book reading. As opposed, I suppose, to magazine reading or comic reading. But a native speaker would be very unlikely to say this.

"Horse" and "race" are both nouns, but both can be used as adjectives. So a "race horse" is a horse of type race, that is, a horse bred or trained for racing. As opposed to, for example, a "plow horse". A "horse race" is a race of type horse, that is, a race involving horses. As opposed to a car race or a boat race. So as I say, you could talk about "book reading" as opposed to "magazine reading", it would be grammatically correct, but it's just not a combination of words that native speakers are likely to saY.